# Show that a sequence converges in distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I recently go through this problem in a past exam and I wonder how to solve this problem. The statement goes as follows:

Let $X_n, n \in \mathbb{N}$ be a sequence of i.i.d random variables satisfying:

$$\mathbb{P}(X_1>x) = \mathbb{P}(X_1<-x) = \frac{1}{2x}$$

for all $x \geq 1$ and let $S_n = X_1 + ... + X_n$. Shows that as $n \rightarrow \infty$, the sequence $\frac{S_n}{n}$ converges in distribution and identify the limit.

Comment: Was this question isolated, or did it came after other questions?

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan it is an isolated question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call $\varphi$ the characteristic function of $X_1$. One checks that the characteristic function of $S_n/N$ is given by $\phi_{S_n/n}(t) = \phi_{S_n}(t/n) = \varphi^n(t/n)$.

Let us look at the behaviour of $\varphi$ at $0$. Since the distribution of $X_1$ is symmetric with regard to $0$, the function $\varphi$ is even. More precisely, for every real number $t$,
$$\varphi(t) 
= \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{itx} \mathbb{1}_{[|x| \ge 1]} \frac{dx}{2x^2}
= \int_1^\infty \cos(tx)\frac{dx}{x^2}.$$
For every $t>0$,
$$\frac{1-\varphi(t)}{t} 
= \int_1^\infty \frac{1-\cos(tx)}{tx^2} dx 
= \int_t^\infty \frac{1-\cos(y)}{y^2}dy.$$
Thus
$$\lim_{t \to 0+} \frac{1-\varphi(t)}{t} \to \int_0^\infty \frac{1-\cos(y)}{y^2}dy = \frac{\pi}{2}.$$
As a result, since $\varphi$ is even,
$$\varphi(t) = 1 - \frac{\pi}{2}|t| + o(t) \textrm{ as } t \to 0.$$
Thus for every real number $t$,
$$\varphi(t/n) = 1 - \frac{\pi|t|}{2n} + o(1/n) \textrm{ as } n \to +\infty.$$
so
$$\phi_{S_n/n}(t) = \varphi^n(t/n) \to \exp(-\pi|t|/2) \textrm{ as } n \to +\infty.$$
The distribution of $S_n/n$ converges to the Cauchy distribution $\mathcal{C}(0,\pi/2)$.